# How to deserialize JSON file starting with an array in Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a Json file that looks like this:

```
[
    { "field":"val" },
....
]
```

I have Java object representing single object and collection of them:

```
public class Objects{

    public Collection<List> myObject;
}
```

I would like to deserialize JSON using `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(in, Objects.class);
```

But I get:

```
11-24 23:19:19.828: W/UpdateService(6084): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not deserialize instance of com.project.my.Objects out of START_ARRAY token
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
   mapper.readValue(in, ObjectClass[].class);
```

Where ObjectClass is something like:

```
  public class ObjectClass {
    String field;

    public ObjectClass() { }

    public void setField(String value) {
      this.field = value;
    }
  }
```

Note: in your posted version of the `Objects` class, you're declaring a Collection of Lists (i.e. a list of lists), which is not what you want. You probably wanted a `List<ObjectClass>`. However, it's much simpler to just do `YourObject[].class` when deserializing with Jackson, and then converting into a list afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

You can directly get a list through the following way:

```
List<ObjectClass> objs =  
    mapper.readValue(in, new TypeReference<List<ObjectClass>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array or List type works, as @dmon answered.

For sake of completeness, there is also an incremental approach if you wanted to read contents one-by-one:

```
Iterator<Objects> it = mapper.reader(Objects.class).readValues(in);
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Objects next = it.next();
  // ... process it
}
```

This is useful if you have huge lists or sequences of objects; either with enclosing JSON Array, or just root-level values separated by spaces or linefeeds.